# Spot Block Instance vs On-Demand AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If I have a batch job that needs higher reliability than a standard spot instance, is there any advantage of using an on-demand instance over a spot instance with a spot block? The job would fall within the 1-6 hour range afforded by a spot block. I've heard of others using an on-demand or dedicated instance to avoid the unreliability of a spot instance even for batch jobs... but reading up on spot blocks, it seems to solve the reliability issue and would be cost optimized, right?

Comment: Right for 1-6 hours reliability and cost saving. By the way, AWS is going to stop support of spot block. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#fixed-duration-spot-instances

Comment: Makes sense... didn't understand why a spot block is even an offering, if anything it just takes away from additional revenue they could generate from on-demand. Thanks for the clarification!